# Regular expression to shorten file paths

Tags: regex

I need to shorten file paths for a report I'm working on for NTFS and share permissions. I'm trying to remove for example `\\` in share paths and `C:\` in drive paths and replace any slashes thereafter with `>`. I also need to shorten the path down to just the last folder but taking into account spaces and special characters. Between the `>` and the folder name it needs a space.

So for example `\\Finance\Accounts & Payroll\Sage` becomes `>> Sage`.

And `D:\HR\Personnel\Records\Holidays\2015` becomes `>>>> 2015`.

Comment: Somewhat tricky to do with just (one) regex. Can't you do something a split-join? Which language do you use?

Comment: Can you add the language you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex-based solution (that at least works with the sample data):

```
echo '\Finance\Accounts & Payroll\Sage
D:\HR\Personnel\Records\Holidays\2015' \
  | perl -pe 's/(^|[^\\]+)\\+/>/g; s/(>*)>/$1 /'
```

↓

```
>> Sage
>>>> 2015
```

<sup>(No language was specified, so I just used my personal favourite. Most regex implementations should work, though.)</sup>

It's a bit of a hack. Another way would be something like (in pseudocode):

```
parts = split(/\\+/, path)
return ('>' × (parts.size - 2) ) ⌢ ' ' ⌢ parts[-1]
```

Keep in mind though that Windows (and others) generally accepts `/` as a separator as well. And that neither of the above take into account things like `..` and `\.\`. Normalising the path first would be a good idea.